# Covert seconds to hours and get input and use function in Python

Tags: python

**Code:1- It is working**

```
def seconds_to_hours(seconds):
    hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
    return hours
print(seconds_to_hours(5000))
```

**Code:2  - It's not working**

```
seconds = input("Enter how many seconds convert to hours?: ")
def seconds_to_hours(seconds):
    hours = seconds / (60 * 60)
    return hours
print(seconds_to_hours)
```

Error is: <function seconds_to_hours at 0x037FC2B0>

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use twice the same name for the main param `seconds` that gets the input, and the function param, also convert the input to `int`

```
def seconds_to_hours(secs):
    return secs / (60 * 60)

seconds = int(input("Enter how many seconds convert to hours?: "))
print(seconds_to_hours(seconds))
```

Comment: What's the problem with using `seconds` as the param too? It will mask the global variable which is a good thing. The main issue with OP's code is that the function is never actually called, not the var name. Good call on `int` though.

Comment: @ggorlen Whatever the name `secs` if you prefer, but not the same to avoid mistaking that's better

Comment: Thanks. I have to write data type in input.